# How to statically translate java class file into assembly code?

Tags: java, assembly

I want to translate a java class file into assembly code. I know JVM provides the option like -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly, if you run a java program with this option, you can get the assembly code. But the problem is I cannot run the java program because the program cannot run by itself, its code will be called by another java application. I need to analyze its assembly code, so I don't want other application's assembly code interfere with me. Is any way I can statically translate the java class file into assembly code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). If you want your Java code to run independent from the calling Java code, run the code in a new JVM, e.g. by starting a new process running the `java` command with a new classpath, and the appropriate compiler options to get the assembly instructions printed.

Comment: "The assembly code" for a function depends on runtime context, including data.  The HotSpot JIT compiler in the most widely used x86 JVMs is quite good, and takes into account runtime data / patterns when deciding how to optimize the asm.  You could get asm from java with [a separate ahead-of-time compiler like GCJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) (based on the gcc backend), but **it won't match what's JITed in the real program**.  Especially not when it's a totally different compiler backend.  Sounds pointless to analyze that.

Comment: Sometimes the JVM may even not bother to produce native machine code, and it will just interpret the java bytecode, if it looks like the code will be run just single time during whole app lifecycle. So it's not-static on "dynamic range" from "none code" to "multiple variants of the same function being used at the same time, depending on the arguments" - not clear which one you want to analyse and why.